# Catch IOException

Tags: java, exception

How can I catch the `IOException`:

```
try {
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter("content.txt");
}
catch(IOException e) {
    return;
}
```

It says it cannot find the class `IOException`.

Any tips will be appreciated.

Comment: You really shouldn't be swallowing exceptions like that...

Comment: @Quirliom I will handle it later.  I am just looking around trying to learn how to import text through a JTextArea with a FileWriter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just state `import java.io.IOException;` before your `class` declaration and after your `package` declaration.

Note: I suggest using an IDE. Most IDE's handle your imports semi-automatically.

Comment: Thank you everybody.  I had just solved it by going (java.io.IOException e).  Thank you for the tips anyway.

Comment: Yes, I am using NetBeans.  It gave me a tip, and I accessed the class directly.

Comment: @user2509848 you're welcome. Referencing the full class path as Hovercraft suggests is perfectly fine. However if you're going to use it more than once in your class it's sort of "cleaner-looking" to just import it. Usually you reference full class paths for classes out of your package when there are potential name clashes and you have to disambiguate.

Comment: Yes, I will probably import for any real program.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the exception at the top of your code:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
```

This allows Java to recognize where the exception class is from.

As such it can catch the exception when it's thrown in your file reading code.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `import` declaration at the top of your source file.

```
import java.io.IOException;    // or
import java.io.*;
```

Or write the fully qualified name. (I would avoid this normally. It's ugly.)

```
catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    return;
}
```

Classes from the [`java.lang`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html) package can be accessed without qualification. Any other package requires an `import` or a fully qualified name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the class first, and you also are missing a variable in your catch expression.

```
catch( IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can skip the import if you fully reference the class:

```
catch(java.io.IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```